# Three images are displayed in output window instead of one

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

Hi everyone i tried using kmeans clustering to group the objects. So that i can use this clustering method to detect objects. I get output but the problem is its too slow{How can i solve this?? } and i get the output window is as shown in the below link. Three output images are displayed instead of one how can i solve this. I don't know where exactly the error lies.

http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=30bd7dc&s=8#.VgkSIPmqqko

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;

using namespace std;

int main(  )
{
  Mat src = imread( "Light.jpg", 0 );
//  imshow("fff",src);
 // cvtColor(src,src,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
  Mat dst;
 // pyrDown(src,src,Size( src.cols/2, src.rows/2 ),4);
 // src=dst;
  resize(src,src,Size(128,128),0,0,1);
  Mat samples(src.rows * src.cols, 3, CV_32F);
  for( int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++ )
    for( int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++ )
    //  for( int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
        samples.at<float>(y + x*src.rows) = src.at<uchar>(y,x);
    cout<<"aaa"<<endl;
  int clusterCount = 15;
  Mat labels;
  int attempts = 2;
  Mat centers;
    cout<<"aaa"<<endl;
  kmeans(samples, clusterCount, labels, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10000, 0.0001), attempts, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers );
  Mat new_image( src.size(), src.type() );
    cout<<"aaa"<<endl;
  for( int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++ )
    for( int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++ )
    { 

      int cluster_idx = labels.at<int>(y + x*src.rows,0);
      new_image.at<uchar>(y,x) = centers.at<float>(cluster_idx,0);
      //new_image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[1] = centers.at<float>(cluster_idx, 1);
     // new_image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[2] = centers.at<float>(cluster_idx, 2);
    }
  imshow( "clustered image", new_image );
  waitKey( 0 );
}
```

Comment: cannot see the image in the link. please update.

Comment: Is there a reason why you've chosen `(y + x*src.rows)` instead of `(y*src.cols + x)`? Memory ordering is one row after the other.

Comment: can you please upload "Light.jpg"?

Comment: what's the reason for 3 channels in `Mat samples(src.rows * src.cols, 3, CV_32F);`? `Mat samples(src.rows * src.cols, 1, CV_32F);` works for me

Comment: @UmNyobe i tried uploading the image but couldn't do successfully.! You can try this sample code with any sample image. Is there any means that, i  can share these images

Comment: @Micka for three channels it works for me aswell..!! if i work with three channels it takes too much time where it will not be helpful for me to detect objects in real time. So i converted this to greyscale.!!

Comment: grayscale is ok but you have to adjust `samples` Mat too, to use 1 channel instead of 3 !!

Comment: @Micka Thank you sir..!! That helped me i didn't notice that !! Is there anyway that i can make it still faster???

Comment: with `(y + x*src.rows)` you jump alot in memory. Better invert that to `(y*src.cols + x)` but not sure whether you have to change more then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your initial code you have to change the intermedia Mat `sample` from 3 channels to 1 channel if you use grayscale images.

In addition, if you change the memory ordering, it might be faster (changed to `(y*src.cols + x, 0)` in both places):

```
int main(  )
{
  clock_t start = clock();

  Mat src = imread( "Light.jpg", 0 );

  Mat dst;
  resize(src,src,Size(128,128),0,0,1);

  Mat samples(src.rows * src.cols, 1, CV_32F);
  for( int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++ )
    for( int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++ )
        samples.at<float>(y*src.cols + x, 0) = src.at<uchar>(y,x);

  int clusterCount = 15;
  Mat labels;
  int attempts = 2;
  Mat centers;

  kmeans(samples, clusterCount, labels, TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10000, 0.0001), attempts, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centers );
  Mat new_image( src.size(), src.type() );

  for( int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++ )
    for( int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++ )
    { 
        int cluster_idx = labels.at<int>(y*src.cols + x,0);
        new_image.at<uchar>(y,x) = centers.at<float>(cluster_idx,0);  
    }
  imshow( "clustered image", new_image );

  clock_t end = clock();
  std::cout << "time: " << (end - start)/(float)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << std::endl;

  waitKey( 0 );
}
```

Comment: Well it worked but i'm not sure whether it is really faster.!! but still there is a delay of 3 to 4 sec even after re seizing the image.

Comment: what's the size of your initial image?

Comment: and on what kind of hardware do you execute the program?

Comment: you should try to measure the time needed for different parts of the code. (time for imread, time for resize, time for the intermediate part, time for kmeans and so on. Those depend on whether you can do things to accelerate the program further. Imho 3 to 4 seconds is way too long for that code, unless the image itself is really big and `resize` needs 3-4 seconds itself, or you're working on quite slow hardware!

Comment: I use 512*512 image,  i5 processor 64 bit operating system, 2Gb ram.

Comment: I need like 0.5 seconds with openCV debug libraries on an i7 ... so probably something is very wrong on your system. Can you try to measure time until cv.:imshow and without cv::imread?

Comment: WoW !!0.5 sec is really good computation time.!! Okay sir i ll see how well i can improve this.!! Thank you once again.!!

Comment: 0.377 s (CPU time) measured, with debug libraries. I'll update the code so you can measure CPU-time yourself.

Comment: it still takes somewhere about 2 sec. Did you update the code??

Comment: code is up-to-date! You should get some terminal output: "time:  xy s". You can move the lines `clock_t start = clock();` and ` clock_t end = clock();` to different positions to measure different timing parts of the code. That way you can measure for example how long only imread takes on your system, or how long kmeans takes on your system and so on, to find out WHICH part of the code is so slow. Please provide that information.

Comment: btw, are you compiling in release mode or in debug mode?

Comment: in debug mode!! yes your inputs really helped me alot time consumption for each step is as shown below                                                                        time taken to read image: 0.046
time taken for resize image:0
time taken for sample matrix:0
time taken to cluster: 0.905
 total time time: 1.014

Comment: each time my timing vary.!! y is that??

Comment: please try release mode, which probably is much faster!